# How to log in as root in KDE?

Tags: kde, kde-neon

Unfortunately the newest KDE neon trips over it's own feet and cannot set up printing:

[(This has nothing to do with the question, but is the reason why I need to run KDE as root; it seems as if Manjaro-users have the same problems as KDE-neon users)](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/adding-printers-on-kde-results-in-failed-to-get-a-list-of-devices-forbidden/46062)

I have set up root with a password and can log in on the command line just fine, but when I try to log into KDE it just fails with "login failed".

Since this can be useful for other situations as well, I would like to know:

How can I log into KDE as root?

Comment: Just use the cups web interface. `localhost:631` in your browser.

Comment: Using cups is probably a cleaner way to setup a printer. Having said that, you could open a tty with Ctrl+Alt+F2, login as root there, and issue `startkde`. Or just run the KDE printer program as root.